# Nested React curly braces not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code with nested React curly braces:

```
{ browser.name === 'firefox' &&
  <a className='foo' href={props.config.site} >
...
}
```

On render, the `href` attribute is entirely missing. The `props` object properly passes in the correct site property as viewed on the Redux addon. To verify that this segment between the outer curly braces is displayed, I have varied the `className` to show that it is this particular element that is presented.

Can I not nest React curly braces in this manner?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the current snippet. Btw. what do you mean with inner/outer curly braces? Is there something relevant inside "..." part?

Comment: `{ browser.name ...` would be the outer curly braces, and `href={props.config.site}` would be the inner curly braces. The href attribute is missing on render.

Comment: It's more html elements without any curly braces.

Comment: Does the `<a>` element appear though or only href gets missing? Have you tried debugging it with something like `<a href={"test"}>`?

Comment: classname -> className

Comment: Did you just try to log props and check the property come inside?

Comment: @RubenKarapetyan Sorry, that's a typo on my part. Not reflected in actual code.

Comment: @jsalonen The `<a>` element indeed does appear. Testing with `<a href={'test'}>` indeed does show `href='test'`. That means it's the props. Ugh. I'm looking into it now. Thanks for the help so far, all.

Comment: Okay, got it figured out. The project uses Immutable.js, and I was unaware that the config was converted into an Immutable.js object. It didn't occur to me to `{ console.log(props.config.site) }` as a way of checking as I would still consider myself relatively inexperienced in React. Lesson learned. Thanks all.

Comment: Great if we could help you!